# Animated Gifs triggering paintComponent (Java)?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, animated-gif, imageicon

While reading religiously through SO, I've seen many examples of using animated gifs in java via the classic:

```
  JLabel mylabel=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("animated.gif"));
```

Which works fine but when I add mylabel to a `JPanel`, I've noticed the JPanel's `paintComponent` method gets called every time the `gif` changes frames.

Is that really necessary?
  Isn't the gif isolated to the JLabel?

It seems like an expensive waste of time to repaint the whole panel (and whatever other components are added to it) every time a gif cycles frames.

In case you're wondering why I care: From doing web design (js/css), I learnt how to avoid reflows almost entirely and isolate repaints to only the element being changed. Worked wonders for performance.

Comment: *"Worked wonders for performance."*  Look into [premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).  This question reeks of it.

Comment: BTW - if `./` means the current directory/package and `../` means the parent directory, what does `.../` mean?

Comment: @AndrewThompson It's not premature. I finished the little application, then noticed the behavior while messing around in the code.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Oh and my bad on the '.../'  Overview on my part. And by 'messing around', I meant exploring/learning. Don't go reading into things that aren't there.

Comment: *"then noticed the behavior while messing around in the code."* How did you notice it?  In the rendering of the GUI or the debugger of the IDE?  If the former, make sure it is not being slowed down by the debugger.  If the latter, it supports what I am saying - there is no need to optimize the code.

Comment: if you are really interested in learning Swing, better stop looking at it with your web design hat on :-)

Comment: @kleopatra I can't help it. I spent so much time in javascript, it's been a real cold water bath taking on java.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm not using an IDE. I've just been writing it by hand in programmers notepad and running from it the command line. I put a 'System.out.println()' in the paintComponent method purely out of curiosity to see what triggered it. Not a smart idea?

Comment: it'll feel much warmer the moment you stop dreaming of the good ol' times :-) Seriously (and aware of sounding like mom :-) - in my experience, it was always necessary to actively "forget" the old ways for a while and fully submerge into the new until I am halfway familiar with the new swimming style. Could be me only, though.

Comment: @kleopatra & AndrewThompson. I really do appreciate the advice and your patience. I understand now why you haven't been particularly impressed by my various questions. I've got a lot of old habits I need to put aside.

Comment: ...this was another warm welcome to the Java Swing world...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is that really necessary?

Yes: the JLabel is not-opaque by default, that's why its parent *must* repaint itself behind on changes of the label .. And if you had explored deeper: the parent *only* repaints the area behind the label (see the clip)

Comment: Fascinating. I can't recall reading that in the javadocs tutorials. (although I might have and didn't absorb it). How do you know all these things offhand without refering back to docs? You must be some sort of........oracle :P

Comment: No, no.  The Oracles **answered to** the Pharaoh.  And yes, I figure putting a `println` in `paintComponent(Graphics)` was not extremely helpful (beyond confirming it was called repeatedly).